# How would i get an existing button to change an object's opacity with html?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I did check this post

[How would i get a button to change a objects opacity with html, js & css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63535469/how-would-i-get-a-button-to-change-a-objects-opacity-with-html-js-css)

to figure out how to change the opacity of an object with a button.
I cannot figure out though how can I customize this code in order to link the opacity of the text to the class or Id of an existing button.

I tried also with

```
document.getElementsByClassName("pippo1").onclick = function() {myFunction()};


function myFunction() {
  document.getElementsByClassName("text1").style.opacity = "1";
}
```

but it does not work.

I could link the "Change Opacity" button to the text editor I want to custom the opacity, but I could not link an existing button to this Function.

```
<html>

<script>

    function myFunction(button) {
       // get data-opacity
       let opacity = button.dataset.opacity;
       const el1 = document.getElementById("text1");
       const el2 = document.getElementById("text2");
       const el3 = document.getElementById("text3");
       const el4 = document.getElementById("text4");
       el1.style.opacity = "1";
       el2.style.opacity = "0";
       el3.style.opacity = "0";
       el4.style.opacity = "0";

      
     }
</script>
</head>
<body>

<button data-opacity="0" class="pippo1" onclick="myFunction(this)">PROJECT</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Can anyone help?

Thank you

Elena

Comment: [getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) returns a **collection**, and as such does not have an onclick property (or a style property). You need to take item [0].

Comment: your code is working fine but you forgot to make elements such as text1, text2, text3 and text4 `<div id="text1">text1</div>
<div id="text2">text2</div>
<div id="text3">text3</div>
<div id="text4">text4</div>`

Comment: I vote to close this question because it is a noob mistake, being found too often and unnecessarily here

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Very much appreciated. I would like to test some of the answers if possible, before closing. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have to take an item of the class like pTag[0], pTag[1](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementsbyclassname.asp)...

The first item is always 0 then 1...

```js
function turnRed() {
  var pTag = document.getElementsByClassName("pTag");
  pTag[0].style.color = "red";
}
```

```html
<button onclick="turnRed()">Turn the p-Tag below red</button>
<p class="pTag">Hello</p>
<p class="pTag">Hello</p>
<p class="pTag">Hello</p>
```

You can also use `querySelector`. This will work for both id and class. But it will only take the first one:

```js
function turnRed() {
  var pTag = document.querySelector(".pTag");
  pTag.style.color = "red";
}
```

```html
<button onclick="turnRed()">Turn the p-Tag below red</button>
<p class="pTag">Hello</p>
<p class="pTag">Hello</p>
<p class="pTag">Hello</p>
```

Also W3Schools made a [documentation](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementsbyclassname.asp)

Answer (score 1):

try this, you can use `classList` to `add`, `remove` or `toggle` CSS `classes`

```js
const button = document.getElementById("button");
const div = document.getElementById("div");

button.addEventListener("click", myfun);

function myfun(){
  div.classList.add("fadeout");
}
```

```css
#div{ width:100px;height:100px;background-color:blue; 
transition:0.5s; }
.fadeout{ opacity:0; visibility:hidden; }
```

```html
<button id="button">Fade</button>
<br>
<div id="div"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Change el1.style.opacity = "1"; to this el1[0].style.opacity = "1";